# c# application holding file even I've finished work with it

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, connection, dbf

I've got an ado.net code listing:

```
OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection();
                //   oconn.ConnectionString ="Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};Provider=vfpoledb.1;SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + pelna_sciezka + ";Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";
                oconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=" + pelna_sciezka + ";Collating Sequence=machine";
                oconn.Open();
                OleDbCommand ocmd = oconn.CreateCommand();
                string na = TBNazwaKonta.Text.Replace("\n","");
                na = na.Replace("\r","") ;
                string ks2 = ks.Replace("\n","");
                ks2 = ks2.Replace("\r", "");
                 OleDbCommand dbCmdNull = oconn.CreateCommand();
                dbCmdNull.CommandText = "SET NULL OFF";
                dbCmdNull.ExecuteNonQuery();                
                string zapytanie = @"insert into " + @pelna_sciezka + @" (rk, Na,Ks) values (0,'" + na + "','" + ks2 +"')";
                ocmd.CommandText = zapytanie;
                ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                oconn.Close();
```

It's working well without any problems. But the dbf file which I using is using by another program. Why if I execute query and close connection the dbf file is still holding by program? If someone want to open it, the error message is 'file access denied'. Only if I close application, the another can get access

Comment: If an Exception is thrown somewhere, you do not actually close the connection. Make use of using statements in your code to cleanup resources that implement IDisposable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Did you try `oconn.Dispose()` (insead of Close)?

Comment: Use a `using` block like Heinzi suggests

Comment: exception is not thrown - all lines is passing well. File access denied is shown when I want to access to dbf file after that from external application. I used using and dispose - it's not working

Answer (score 5):

You are not closing your OleDbCommands. Contrary to SqlCommands, where this is de facto optional, this *does* make a difference for OleDb.

I recommend to use the `using` keyword; this ensures that all resources are released automatically at the end of the block. As an additional bonus, it ensures that the resources are also released if an exception occurs and, thus, your manual `Close` command would never be reached.

```
using (OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection()) {
    oconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=" + pelna_sciezka + ";Collating Sequence=machine"; 
    oconn.Open(); 

    using (OleDbCommand ocmd = oconn.CreateCommand()) {
        string na = TBNazwaKonta.Text.Replace("\n",""); 
        na = na.Replace("\r","") ; 
        string ks2 = ks.Replace("\n",""); 
        ks2 = ks2.Replace("\r", ""); 

        using (OleDbCommand dbCmdNull = oconn.CreateCommand()) {
            dbCmdNull.CommandText = "SET NULL OFF"; 
            dbCmdNull.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } // closes dbCmdNull

        string zapytanie = @"insert into " + @pelna_sciezka + @" (rk, Na,Ks) values (0,'" + na + "','" + ks2 +"')"; 
        ocmd.CommandText = zapytanie; 
        ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }  // closes ocmd
} // closes connection
```

Comment: I'm using this - the file access denied is still shown. Maybe it is a way to open the file not exclusive?

Comment: @BKI: Can you narrow it down? Can you produce a *minimal* example (e.g. only open connection, only execute a single command, etc.) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Your code is working well, but second application which is using this dbf file too, hasn't access to the file until I close the main application. Maybe it is a problem with Garbage Collector? I'll try to use not exclusive connection

Comment: @BKI: I understand that. Still, can you produce a *minimal* example?

Comment: I am not sure if I well understood you but: ConnectionString: Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=D:\\transmisja\\nch2\\konta.dbf;Collating Sequence=machine query: insert into D:\\transmisja\\nch2\\konta.dbf (rk, Na,Ks) values (0,'Jankowicz Józefa','200 23 010e4')

Comment: It's what is using after running program.

Comment: @BKI: This is what I mean by minimal example: http://sscce.org/ The goal is to find out which operation *exactly* causes the file to be left open.

Comment: I found something like that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260856 If you wait 60seconds, the dbf is available. Thanks for help. Now I'll be looking for method, how shorten this period

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem, there were two points that I performed:
- I've changed all `ado.net` code for that like Heinzi has written 
- I've used the information from `support.microsoft.com/kb/260856`

and followed them, the problem has now disappeared. Thank you all for help!